# What is the full form of this sloka?

Tags: identification-request, food, chaitanya, sannyasa, chaitanya-charitamrita

To support His opinion that as per the scriptures, a  sannyasin has NO restrictions on food, Sri Advaita Acharya, a friend of Lord Sri Chaitanya quotes the following part of a scriptural sloka:

> nAnna-doshena maskari (Sri Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita, Madhya Khanda, chapter 12, sloka 374)

What is the full sloka? Please cite the origin also.

Comment: The "food" tag is also apt here but no spaces left for another tag, probably u can drop gaudiya-vaisnavism

Comment: Btw I think it was quoted by Advaita Acharya, not Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury yes thanks.mI checked. editing.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury He referred to Mahaprabhu by Prabhu' I think btw

Comment: Yes he did. @Pratimaputra

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full shloka is:

> न वायुः स्पर्शदोषेण नाग्निर्दहनकर्मणा ।
>   नापो मूत्रपुरीषाभ्यां **नान्नदोषेण मस्करी** [॥ ७२॥](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/sanyasa.html?lang=sa)

It's from **Sannyasa Upanishad**.

> na vAyuH sparshadoSheNa nAgnirdahanakarmaNA .
>   nApo mUtrapurIShAbhyA.n **nAnnadoSheNa maskarI** [.. 72..](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/sanyasa.itx)

Note that I found some inconsistency in numbering of verses e.g. This verse is 72<sup>th</sup> according to [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/sanyasa.html?lang=sa) and [wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D) versions but it's 90<sup>th</sup> according to [upanishads.org](https://upanishads.org.in/otherupanishads/34) and [Vedanta Spritual Library](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-sama-veda/sannyasa-upanishad/) versions.

English translation:

> [90.](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-sama-veda/sannyasa-upanishad/) Air is not spoiled by touching (any object); fire by the activity of burning; waters, by urine and faeces (getting into them); and a mendicant monk by short-comings in food.

Regarding the part of shloka mentioned in the question, the "short-comings" in the translation should be taken as Dosha i.e faults according to Sanskrit text.

Comment: But none of the editions of Chaitanya Charitamrita coukd provide the sloka.So you deserve the greatest appreciation.

Comment: @Pratimaputra you can offer [bounty](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) with option that "one of the existing answers is worthy of bounty"! Lol

Comment: Actually it's present in verse 191 of the Prabhupada version. @Pratimaputra

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury okay thnx. Is the source also nentioned? I meant the books edited by the scholars in Bengali. I never read that version.

Comment: @Pratimaputra No, it doesn't mention that.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury okay thnx