# Meat and fish eating in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, food, non-vegetarian

A question has been bugging my mind for a few days-Is eating meat and fish explicitly forbidden in Vedas?I want to know the truth with vedic reference.

Comment: Meat and fish eating is not forbidden in vedas, as far as I know.

Comment: Vedic reference pls

Comment: @OpiChowdhury https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34218/18023 read it.

Comment: As per Veda, there is no restrictions. On the contrary there used to be yajna in which animal sacrifice and its meat offering was part of the process.

Comment: Yes, meat and fish eating is forbidden except during sacrifices, from the Chhandogya Upanishad:

He who has learnt the Veda from a family of teachers, according to the sacred rule, in the leisure time left from the duties to be performed for the Guru, who, after receiving his discharge, has settled in his own house, keeping up the memory of what he has learnt by repeating it regularly in some sacred spot, who has begotten virtuous sons, and concentrated all his senses on the Self, n**ever giving pain to any creature, except at the tîrthas (sacrifices, &c.),**

Answer (score 2):

No, meat and fish eating is not explicitly forbidden in the Vedas. Complete avoidance of fish and meat is only an option.

> He who thus knows this Yajnayajniya Saman, woven in the limbs of the
>   body, is endowed with all the limbs of the body, and is not crippled
>   in any limb; he reaches the full length of life, lives gloriously,
>   becomes great with offspring and cattle and great also with fame.
>   **His holy vow is that he should not eat fish and meat for a year, or rather, he should not eat fish and meat at all.**

Chandogya Upanishad 2.19.2

Comment: so it is said that meat should be avoided but not explicitly forbidden?and can I have vedic reference

Comment: Chandogya Upanishad is part of the Vedas. I do not know if there is anything in the Vedic Samhitas.

Comment: In Geeta Sattvic,Rajasic and tamasic food has been mentioned but it is not mentioned whether meat is sattvic or not

Comment: Upanishads contain the highest truth of the Vedas.It is there in the Upanishad and so full proof evidence.

Comment: @OpiChowdhury, yes gita does not explicitly talk about meat. Read my answer to the question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34096/did-vivekananda-do-prayaschitta-to-atone-for-his-sin-of-eating-meat-as-a-sannyas

Comment: @OpiChowdhury yes if u see the characteristics of the tamasik food minutely, fish and meat ARE tamasik even though not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @OpiChowdhury please read the meanings of 'puti' and 'amedhya'

Comment: You should probably add a reference to [the previous verse](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc238895.html) too and this commentary: "**We get much nourishment from animals to sustain our bodies. That is why, in the previous section, the Sāma has been worshipped in the animals**, and now it is being worshipped in the various parts of the body." Also, in [2.19.2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc238896.html), the word _majjña_ is apparently plural form of meat though there is no direct reference to fish.

Comment: @sv. fish is also included in meat in broder sense, isnt it?

Comment: @Pratimaputra By that logic, you can also include beef, pork and other types of meat?

Comment: @sv. whatever can be offered in a yajna is included.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Do you have an example of fish being offered? I know for sure beef was offered. BTW, according to [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22764) 299 different species were sacrificed.

Comment: @sv. in tantrik pujas fish is offered.

Comment: @sv. and in Bengal in sraddha also of the widows

Comment: @OpiChowdhury https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34218/18023 read it.

Comment: @sv. In Tantra ritual, meat and madira are offered to Goddess. :-)

Answer (score 1):

rig veda 1.187 eulogizes nourishment offered by food to humans and this food only comprises of plant and milk i.e vegetarian:

> *8 Whatever morsel we consume from **waters or from plants of earth**, O Soma, wax thou fat thereby.*
> *9 What Soma, we enjoy from thee in **milky food or barley-brew**, Vātāpi, grow thou fat thereby.*
> *10 O **Vegetable, Cake of meal**, he wholesome, firm, and strengthening: Vātāpi, grow thou fat thereby.*

From this we can infer that vedas only prescribe vegetarian food for humans.

Other vedic verses which talk of meat, animals etc. are not in context of human food and hence cannot be taken on face value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meat and fish eating is forbidden except during sacrifices, from the Chhandogya Upanishad:

> He who has learnt the Veda from a family of teachers, according to the sacred rule, in the leisure time left from the duties to be performed for the Guru, who, after receiving his discharge, has settled in his own house, keeping up the memory of what he has learnt by repeating it regularly in some sacred spot, who has begotten virtuous sons, and concentrated all his senses on the Self, **never giving pain to any creature, except at the tîrthas (sacrifices, &c.),** he who behaves thus all his life, reaches the world of Brahman, and does not return, yea, he does not return.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01175.htm

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Why not?

Comment: Your answer throws no light on whether its forbidden or not.One who eats the offered meat or fish does not slay the animals himself.Further, for non-trivarnas your quotation is not applicable at all.

Comment: @Pratimaputra But if you eat the meat, you have supported the killing.